# two documents sharing same reference numbering

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a scientific paper with supplementary information in an additional document. The paper and the supplement share many references, which in the paper are numbered by first appearance in the text.

I would like the references in the supplement to have the same numbers as in the paper. I have additional references there and not all references from the paper show up in the supplement.

I am still working on the documents and the `.bib`-file is changing. It is generated by [Icculus Referencer](http://icculus.org/referencer/).

Is there a way to achieve the numbering the way I like? I haven't tried, but I think, that one way could be to create a `.bib`-file with all references that I want to use and then number all of them, regardless of their use in the current document. The problem is, that when I change the first appearance of one reference, I have to change the order of the bibtex-entries in the `.bib`-files, which is not very handy.

Comment: Should the bibliography in the supplement contain also the referenced items that appear in the main document?

Comment: @egreg, that is not specified by the journal, so it does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `\nocite` command (see this [Wikibook entry](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#No_Cite) for a quick explanation)... there's also a `\nocite{*}` command to list a whole `bib` file (see this [TeX FAQ entry](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nocite*)).

EDIT: referring to my comment below... I came up with an **UGLY** Python script to do just that:

```
import re

# input and output files
input = 'in.tex'
output = 'out.tex'

# remove duplicates whilst preserving order
def uniq (seq):
    seen = set ()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add (x)]

# pattern to look for
pat = '((\\cite)|(\\citet)|(\\citep)|(\\citet\*)|(\\citep\*)|(\\citeauthor)|(\\citeauthor\*)|(\\citeyear)|(\\citeyearpar)|(\\citealt)|(\\citealp))(\[.*?\])?\{(.*?)\}'

# get the file
f = open (input)
#read it into i
i = f.read ()
# close it
f.close ()

# get the list of references, with no duplicates, and preserving order
ms = uniq ((','.join ([(list (x))[-1:][0] for x in re.findall (pat, i)])).split (','))

# initialize output to empty string
o = ''

# for every reference...
for m in ms:
  # generate \nocite command
  o += '\\nocite{' + m + '}\n'

# open output file
f = open (output, 'w')
# write output away
f.write (o)
# close it
f.close ()
```

change `input` (`in.tex`) and `output` (`out.tex`) as needed, run it through Python, and you'll get the `\nocite`s in the order in which they first appeared in the input file.

Hope it helps! ;)

EDIT 2: changed the regular expression to support all the cite type given [in this Wikibook entry](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib).

Comment: `\nocite{*}` is helpful for listing uncited bibentries in the bibliography. The OP's question, however, is about a "unified" numbering scheme for multiple documents.

Comment: @lockstep: Although this is not the answer to my problem, it hints to a painful workaround. Using \nocite{*} on a bibliography, that is preordered according to first appearance of citations in a document, I get the right numbering of citations in the document, but unfortunately all the references are listed in both documents. If I could find a way to filter the unused ones out again, I would be fine. Unfortunately there are 2 problems: 1. I have to presort the bibliography, 2. I don't know, how to eliminate the unused references.

Comment: I think one could write a Python / Perl / Bash / whatever script to get the reference's keys from your "main" paper (by looking for `\cite` commands), then write out `\nocite`s for them to a file, say `mainrefs.tex`. Then in your "secondary" paper you could `\input{mainrefs}` at the very beginning ;)

Comment: Done just that in the answer proper ;)

Answer (score 2):

A solution I used is to keep both documents as a single document until the very end.  Then manually split the bibliography and adjust the appropriate counters as discussed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37651/6903).  You can also reset the page counter for the supplementary material when submitting (but keep consecutive pages if you post the complete document somewhere like a preprint server or for your own use).

This is a bit of a pain, but since (for me) I need to manually include the `.bbl` file in the main text for both the preprint server and the final submission, it is not really that onerous.

By using some hooks from `etoolbox`, all I need to do is to figure out where to split the bibliography, then include two separate bibliographies in the file.  (I put all of this stuff and a copy of the preamble from the `.bbl` file in a local style file so I don't have to worry about it when writing the paper.)

```
\documentclass[aps, prl, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % Provides ability to hook into thebibliography
\makeatletter         % Some cmds have @ in them.  Not needed if in a .sty file
\newcounter{firstbib} % New counter: keeps track of the next first number 

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{
  % Insert the first portion of the .bbl file here defining any formatting
  % macros
}

% Can't use \AtBeginEnvironment for the next bit since that is too early.
% We need to set the counter *after* the \thebibliography command is used.
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{
  \setcounter{NAT@ctr}{\value{firstbib}} % Use this for natbib and revtex
  %\setcounter{enumiv}{\value{firstbib}} % ... or you might need to use this
}{}{}  % These args are for errors handling: see etoolbox docs

\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{
  \setcounter{firstbib}{\value{NAT@ctr}}
  %\setcounter{firstbib}{\value{enumiv}}
}

\begin{document}
\title{A Great Paper (with Supplementary Material)}

\begin{abstract}\noindent
  This demonstrates using two bibliographies with continuous numbering, but
  separation into a main bibliography and a supplementary bibliography.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\noindent
First write the paper with a single bibliography and cite everything as
normal. Then, when finished, manually split the \texttt{.bbl} file in two at
the appropriate place and include each portion in its own environment.
Adjust the counters as needed.  Here is a reference in the main text:
\cite{Zwerger:2011}.

% Use these as needed when working, and use bibtex.
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
%\bibliography{master}

% Insert the first portion of the .bbl file here:
\begin{thebibliography}{74}
\bibitem{Zwerger:2011}%
  W.~Zwerger, ed., \emph{The BCS--BEC Crossover and the Unitary Fermi Gas},
  Lecture Notes in Physics, Vol.~836 (Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg,
  2012) \makeatletter
\end{thebibliography}

\clearpage
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Supplementary Material}\noindent
Here is some supplementary material.  You can refer to the original
references~\cite{Zwerger:2011} or include new references~\cite{Forbes:2012}.

\begin{thebibliography}{74}
\bibitem{Forbes:2012}%
  M.~M.~Forbes, S.~Gandolfi, and A.~Gezerlis, Phys.~Rev.~A \textbf{86},
  053603 (2012)
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

### References

- [Manual bibliography, separated or multiple parts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37649)