# Manual bibliography, separated or multiple parts

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, naming

I'm creating a manual bibliography, but it needs to be divided into sections. The solutions I thought might be applicable:

- Add `\textbx{"Literary works"}`, `\textbx{"Web references"}`, etc. between `\bibitem{}` items. This does not work, since an error is reported.
- Insert separate bibliographies and label them accordingly (which I don't know how to do).

Any help / other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: is this in an article or a multi-chapter work?  (makes a difference.)

Comment: Multi-chapter work. A book (literature dissertation). Lots of footnotes and several parts in bib.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Create several separate `thebibliography` environments;
- Redefine the `\bibname` macro (for the `book` and `report` class)  or the `\refname` macro (for the `article` class) before every environment as desired;
- To achieve unambiguous numbering of your bibitems, define a new counter (say, `firstbib`), use this counter to save the value of `enumiv` at the end of every `thebibliography` environment and reset `enumiv` to the value of `firstbib` at the start of the next environment.
- (Note, however, that if you're using `natbib`, then the counter is `NAT@ctr` instead of `enumiv`.)

Because the redefinitions of `\bibname`/`\refname` take place after `\begin{document}`, this solution also works if one uses the `babel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{firstbib}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

Some text \cite{A01,B02,C03}.

\renewcommand{\refname}{Literary works}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{A01} A. Author. \emph{Alpha}. 2001.

\bibitem{B02} B. Buthor. \emph{Bravo}. 2002.

\setcounter{firstbib}{\value{enumiv}}

\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Web references}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\setcounter{enumiv}{\value{firstbib}}

\bibitem{C03} C. Cuthor. \emph{Charlie}. 2003.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Excellent suggestion -- I changed my example accordingly. (And yes, I know this in principle, but totally forgot it at the moment.)

Comment: ...and I updated it in my document! :) Thank you, both of you. Works like charm.

Comment: Just a note that if you use ``natbib``, then the counter is ``NAT@ctr`` not ``enumiv``.

Answer (score 3):

A much easier solution is using the `biblatex` package and defining a `refsection` environment in the body of the chapter.

```
\chapter{Blah}
\begin{refsection}% 3rd `refsection`

\end{refsection}
```

To print the bibliography you use:

```
\printbibliography[section=3,title={Blah Bibliography}]
```

The only difference is that you have to run `bibtex` for each `*-blx.aux` file.

Creating bibliographies that depend on criteria is also possible.