# Force no breaks after manual bibliographies in book doc class

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, page-breaking, chapters

After successfully applying tips on how to [insert multiple manual bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37649/manual-bibliography-separated-or-multiple-parts) I have a new problem: each bibliography begins on a new page. This does not look good, and I tried supressing it with `\nopagebreak` (does not work).

After some browsing I discovered that `book` class handles `thebibliography` by inserting new chapter, but I don't know how to modify the behaviour.

So, my question is: how to stop inserting new page/heading after each `thebibliography` item in a `book` document class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a) disable `\clearpage` inside a group b) add a `\chapter*{Bibliography}` and patch `\thebibliography` so that it uses `\section*` instead of `\chapter*`.

EDIT: Added code to correct running headers for `\section*` (sub)bibliographies.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\patchthebibliography}{%
  \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
  }{%
    \markright{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
  }{}{} %
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{firstbib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}.

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literary works}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{A01} A. Author. \emph{Alpha}. 2001.

\setcounter{firstbib}{\value{enumiv}}

\end{thebibliography}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Web references}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\setcounter{enumiv}{\value{firstbib}}

\bibitem{B02} B. Buthor. \emph{Bravo}. 2002.

\end{thebibliography}

\endgroup

\begingroup
\patchthebibliography

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}{\MakeUppercase{Bibliography}}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literary works}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{A01} A. Author. \emph{Alpha}. 2001.

\setcounter{firstbib}{\value{enumiv}}

\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Web references}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\setcounter{enumiv}{\value{firstbib}}

\bibitem{B02} B. Buthor. \emph{Bravo}. 2002.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you might consider making a separate environment, `inchapterbibliography`; it's basically just a clone of `thebibliography` with `\chapter*` replaced by `\section*`.  some books have both kinds of reference lists, so it's handy to be able to make the choice.  (this feature is on the list to be added to `amsbook` in the next upgrade, not yet scheduled.)

Comment: The solution worked great, thanks! First I edited the main file by inserting `\newcommand` code. Then, I inserted `\patchthebibliography` at the beginning of the file with the manual bibliographies. That was all it was needed.