# Sort bibliography file according to order of appearance of citations in LaTeX document

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I am asking this question, because there does not seem to be an easy way in LaTeX to solve this problem: [two documents sharing same reference numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36349/two-documents-sharing-same-reference-numbering).

My question: Is it possible to order a bibliography according to the order of appearance in a LaTeX document.

What I originally wanted to do is mentioned in the link above, but as a workaround I would like to presort the references according to order of appearance in one document and give them the same citation numbers in the other document. I could then use `\nocite{*}` to the same bibliography in both documents with the same reference-numbers.

Comment: Have a look at [Bibliography Style - Order of Appearance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/bibliography-style-order-of-appearance), and [some other questions containing 'order of appearance'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=order+of+appearance)

Comment: Very short answer (beside looking at the previous links provided by cmhugues) : use `biblatex` and specify the `presort` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is much easier than the other.

You can get the bibliography in order of appearance with

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

if not using `biblatex`, or with the option `sorting=none` to `biblatex`. Say that your main document is `sebastianmain.tex`. Compile it and run `bibtex` (or `biber`).

Don't load any package for the bibliography in the secondary document and say

```
\input{sebastianmain.bbl}
```

where the bibliography should appear; or

```
\begin{lrbox}{0}\input{sebastianmain.bbl}\end{lrbox}
```

if you don't want the bibliography to appear. In the secondary document you can use the same keys as in the main one.